# DXA: AbstractController - Region not found on page: Social

Tags: dxa

I have added new Component Templates that will render on two new Regions created under a generic module that was created exclusively for our website entiry, Region and Page separate from the core views.

I have published the settings and the new region appears in the `regions.json` file as

```
{"Region":"Generic:Social","ComponentTypes":[{"Schema":"tcm:3-151-8","Template":"tcm:3-522-32"}]},
```

The name of region mentioned in metadata of template is also the same. 
the region `Social.jsp` has just one entry:

```
<tri:entities region="Generic:Social"/>
```

When I run the Page I get the following error:

> A problem occurred while rendering this section

The logs show:

> 17:34:29.586 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] ERROR c.s.w.c.c.AbstractController - Region not found on page: Social
>   17:34:29.592 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] ERROR c.s.w.c.c.AbstractController - Exception while processing request for: http://10.0.0.48:8080/WEB-INF/Views/Core/Page/GeneralPage.jsp
>       com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.exception.NotFoundException: Region not found on page: Social
>           at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.AbstractController.getRegionFromRequest(AbstractController.java:56) ~[common-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
>           at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.AbstractController.getEntityFromRequest(AbstractController.java:63) ~[common-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
>           at com.sdl.webapp.main.controller.core.EntityController.handleGetEntity(EntityController.java:47) ~[core-module-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor207.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) ~[spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:934) [jasper.jar:8.0.23]
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:646) [jasper.jar:8.0.23]
>           at com.sdl.webapp.common.markup.AbstractMarkupTag.decorateInclude(AbstractMarkupTag.java:34) [common-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
>           at com.sdl.webapp.main.taglib.tri.EntitiesTag.doStartTag(EntitiesTag.java:42) [core-module-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Views.Generic.Region.Social_jsp._jspx_meth_tri_005fentities_005f0(Social_jsp.java:133) [ROOT/:na]
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Views.Generic.Region.Social_jsp._jspService(Social_jsp.java:100) [ROOT/:na]

Comment: Does your PT has reference added to this region? something like `<tri:region name="Social"/>` or any generic entry to exclude particular region and display other `<tri:regions exclude="others" />` (This will display all regions part from `others.jsp`)

Comment: Yes, it does. First I added something like this  `<div class="col-sm-6 social"><tri:region name="Social"/></div>` and nothing showed. So then I changed the name to `Generic:Social` and thats when I got the above error.

Comment: I created a Core folder under Views and moved the new region from my module to this Core and it appears. So do I have to create all my new regions under Core.

Answer (score 1):

The prefix to your Region name defines the Module name, and also specifies where DXA will search for the region view. All views for a certain module must be placed in an Area by that same name.

In your case `Generic:Social` defines that you must have a Module named **General** and a view named **Social** which should be in an Area named **General**.

Since you mention in the comments it is working when you move the views in a folder named **Core**, it sounds like you have some misconfiguration somewhere in your Module and the location of your views. Moving everything to the Core module and Core area is not really the solution, that sounds more like a workaround ignoring the actual misconfiguration issue.